# Rails ActionCable and React Native

Tags: react-native, websocket, actioncable

I'm working on a companion React Native app to accompany my RoR webapp, and want to build a chat feature using ActionCable (websockets). I cannot get my React Native app to talk to ActionCable.

I have tried a number of libraries including [react-native-actioncable](https://github.com/cpunion/react-native-actioncable) with no luck. The initial connection seems to be working (I know this because I was having errors before and they've since gone away when I passed the proper params).

This is an abbreviated version of my React Native code:

```
import ActionCable from 'react-native-actioncable'

class Secured extends Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    var url = 'https://x.herokuapp.com/cable/?authToken=' + this.props.token + '&client=' + this.props.client + '&uid=' + this.props.uid + '&expiry=' + this.props.expiry
    const cable = ActionCable.createConsumer(url)

    cable.subscriptions.create('inbox_channel_1', {
      received: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
      }
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TabBarNavigation/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    email: state.auth.email,
    org_id: state.auth.org_id,
    token: state.auth.token,
    client: state.auth.client,
    uid: state.auth.uid,
    expiry: state.auth.expiry
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { })(Secured)
```

Anyone with more experience connecting ActionCable to React Native and can help me out?

Comment: Hey. I suggest you to try https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kesha-antonov/react-native-action-cable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url endpoint you're attaching to is not a websocket, so that's probably your issue. [The example app](https://github.com/cpunion/TestRNActionCable/blob/87caa99e541c96418048e38023d3f9574a0e7e6e/main.js) they've listed was updated just 2 months ago and is based on RN 0.48.3, so I have to guess that it probably still works. Have you tried cloning and running it?

Looks like you'll also need to setup a provider as well (<ActionCableProvider>)

```
import RNActionCable from 'react-native-actioncable';
import ActionCableProvider, { ActionCable } from 'react-actioncable-provider';

const cable = RNActionCable.createConsumer('ws://localhost:3000/cable');

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        messages: []
    }

    onReceived = (data) => {
        this.setState({
            messages: [
                data.message,
                ...this.state.messages
            ]
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ActionCable channel={{channel: 'MessageChannel'}} onReceived={this.onReceived} />
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <View>
            <Text>There are {this.state.messages.length} messages.</Text>
        </View>
        {this.state.messages.map((message, index) =>
            <View key={index} style={styles.message}>
                <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                  {message}
                </Text>
              </View>
          )}
      </View>
      )
    }
}

export default class TestRNActionCable extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <ActionCableProvider cable={cable}>
          <App />
         </ActionCableProvider>
    );
  }
}
```